# Clean up an htaccess from infections

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, web, malware

I have a simple wordpress website and it seems to be hacked. I used some plugins to scan it and they say my `htaccess` file is infected. Now I could use some help clean it up - specifically, to understand

- What to look for to clean up? I.e. what does an "infection" in `htaccess` look like?
- how can I prevent unauthorized access to the file in the future?

The `htaccess` in question is:
http://pastebin.com/TcWiQvNP

Comment: Protecting your site from attacks is too broad a topic for a single SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's default wordpress htaccess

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

also for permission
set chmd to 644

Answer (score 0):

First, you need basic understanding of `mod_rewrite` configuration structure to understand what your current file does and be able to edit it correctly.

Now, the broadly defined redirects to some absolute URLs do look suspicious. But I don't know if the URLs correspond to your site or some other.

In general, you need to identify which directives are "alien" - i.e. do not correspond to the apps you're running at the server.